# Is there a way to remove the background when taking a picture from the network in Swift 5 and reflect it in the imageView?

Tags: swift, uikit

I will receive image data from a url and I want to remove the background of the incoming images. And I don't know how to do this. I need your help.

I have an imageView in a collectionview. And I want the pictures to show only the outline.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with `UIKit` only since you need some image processing tools, you can achieve this easily with `CoreML` powered libraries, to process the `UIImage` after downloading it from the `url` and then pass the processed one to the `UIImageView`:

[here's an example.](https://medium.com/macoclock/remove-the-image-background-in-swift-using-core-ml-8646ed3a1c14)

Or ideally create your custom `UIImageView` which does all that in itself, encapsulate all the logic in your custom `UIImageView` and then simply use it whenever you need it.

[Apple's Core ML Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml)